# Why views are not updated on runnable in android widget?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make one of the views in android widget visible for a second, but so far no success. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

I've tried to do it with animation, timer but so far I got the nearest with runnable. Well, kind of as I get System.out.println("run test") executed but views are not updated.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (MinutesClicked.equals(intent.getAction())){
        //your onClick action is here

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        final RemoteViews views;
        ComponentName appWidget;

        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.nixie_clock);
        appWidget = new ComponentName(context, NixieClock.class);

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                views.setViewVisibility(R.id.textDateDay, VISIBLE);
                System.out.println("run test");
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidget, views);
    }
}
```

So far I am getting System.out.println("run test") printed but expected views are not made VISIBLE. I can make the view visible after a click but I cannot make it appear only for a second and disappear. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the `RemoteViews`, but you are not sending the updated `RemoteViews` anywhere. You need to call `updateAppWidget()` again after updating the `RemoteViews`.

Note that your process might be terminated before the one-second delay elapses, in which case your view will not become visible.